# ROS Listener (Hydro) Not Working

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Android 4.2.2, Android 4.1.2, Ubuntu 12.04, Android Studio 0.4.4, ROS Hydro

Hi, I have recently tried to run the listener (obtained from Google Play) through Robot Remocon, but after the "Starting Listener" dialog box disappeared, no new view (window) is opened, it is still on the main layout of the Remocon, with the Listener highlighted blue (indicating running app), and the ability to stop the app. Apart from that, even though a new ROS topic is created under "/turtlebot/chatter", I can't see any data on my device (since apparently the rosTextView has failed to be opened?).

I would really appreciate it if anyone can look into this.

PS: I have tried to compile the code from "android_apps" under Android Studio myself, and the same problem has occurred.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129156/ros-listener-(hydro)-not-working/) by [Hon Ng](https://answers.ros.org/users/11956/hon-ng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-02-17**:
Do you have your ROS_IP/ROS_HOSTNAME variables set?

**Comment by [Hon Ng](https://answers.ros.org/users/11956/hon-ng/) on 2014-02-18**:
Yes, otherwise, the Robot Remocon App will not connect successfully to the turtlebot, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot remocon is not just a way of starting android apps, you can also use it to just fire up launch configurations on the robot. That's what you are seeing here (albeit unintentionally). You'll note that there are two rocon rapps available, one is talker, one is listener.

The [talker rapp](https://github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon_app_platform/blob/hydro/rocon_apps/apps/talker/talker.rapp) has a launcher that starts a ros tutorials talker on the robot. In that configuration file, you'll also see it has a defined pairing client for android - a listener android app. i.e. the robot starts the launcher, the android starts the pairing client.

The [listener rapp](https://github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon_app_platform/blob/hydro/rocon_apps/apps/listener/listener.rapp) doesn't have a pairing client (yet - simply because we never got around to writing it). So it fires up the listener on the robot, but doesn't do anything on the robot side.

This behaviour can be useful if you just want to use the robot remocon for starting and stopping launch configurations on your robot.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hon Ng](https://answers.ros.org/users/11956/hon-ng/) on 2014-02-19**:
Ok, I see, thank you.

But unfortunately, the source code for the talker is not on here: https://github.com/rosjava/android_apps/tree/hydro

Or did I missed something?

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-02-19**:
It's the https://github.com/rosjava/android_apps/tree/hydro/listener. The robot side runs the 'talker', the android side is the 'listener'. It's a bit confusing, but we went with the convention of naming robot apps from the robot's perspective for this pairing mode.

**Comment by [Hon Ng](https://answers.ros.org/users/11956/hon-ng/) on 2014-02-23**:
Ok, that makes more sense. Cheers! =D